# How to create a universal jquery validate and reset function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, validation, reset

I am using the jquery validate plugin to create a validation method for all forms in an application. Using the jquery each() function to cycle each form and applyt the method. I want to achieve the reset using the same each method. how can i accomplish this?

This is the code that works:

```
 $("form").each(function () { 
        $(this).validate(); 
    });
```

This is the code that doesn't

```
   $("form").each(function () { 
        validator = $(this).validate(); 
        validator.resetForm();
        $("#reset").click(function () {
            validator.resetForm();
        });
    });
```

Please advise..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the `var` keyword, you're setting `validator` as a global variable, and changing what it's set to with each loop (so it'll be set the to the validator of the last form at the end), just add `var` when declaring it, like this:

```
$("form").each(function () { 
   var validator = $(this).validate();  //add var here
   validator.resetForm();
   $("#reset").click(function () {
       validator.resetForm();
   });
});
```

This will correct it so you'll reset each `<form>` once, rater than the last `<form>` `n` times.

Comment: $("form").each(function () {
            var validator = $(this).validate();  //add var here
            validator.resetForm();
            $(this).children("#reset").click(function () {
                validator.resetForm();
            });
        });

Answer (score 1):

try this maybe?

```
$("form").each(function () { 
var validator = $(this);
validator.validate(); 
validator.resetForm(); 
$("#reset").click(function () { 
    validator.resetForm(); 
}); 
 });
```