# Error message not get cleared while clicking the reset button

Tags: jquery, validation, reset

I am using jquery.validate.js file to validate an input form, It works fine, my problem is the error messages are not get cleared while clicking the reset button in the form.

how to get clear the form?

**here is the code**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>


  javascript function

      $(document).ready(function(){        

        $("#demo-form").validate({    
          rules: {
            name: "required",
            address: "required",
       }
```

HTML Code

```
<div><input type="text" id="name" name="name" /></div>

<div><input type="text" id="address" name="address" /></div>

<div> <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Validate!" />
      <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
```

Comment: -1: Question is too vague - please post some code samples

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reset required fields - jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047664/reset-required-fields-jquery)

Comment: Please remember to use the code function to highlight your code, otherwise we won't be able to see it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a universal jquery validate and reset function call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311317/how-to-create-a-universal-jquery-validate-and-reset-function-call)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, when you click the reset button. It will be responsible for clearing the fields, not the label. Normally, jquery validate plugin, keeps its validation messages in labels. So in order to clear them, use

```
$('label.error').remove();
```

call this on the click of reset button
where it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try hiding them by calling CSS hide property on your error DIV's when you press reset button